# What's the best way to clear a container in C++?

Tags: c++, list, set

What is the best, fastest and most reliable way to clear `std::list` and `std::set`?

```
// 1st
list.clear();
set.clear();

// 2nd
list = {};
set = {};

// 3rd
list.swap(std::list<some_type>{});
set.swap(std::set<some_type>{});
```

Comment: Is it a coincidence that your example is with two node-based containers? Because for `std::vector`, the semantic of the operations shown differs. If you are already aware of this, maybe mention it to the question.

Comment: I already knew about the `std::vector swap trick` and since I have a class that uses those two data structures internally, I got curious.

Comment: Just look at the generated asm from an optimized build with a modern compiler and you have your answer - 5min of work tops.

Comment: As a side note, shouldn't the ultimate answer be deemed implementation-dependent? Because despite all the complexities and properties the standard requires should hint at specific implementations (so-and-so), the exact implementation is technically unspecified.

Answer (score 5):

All those options will be roughly of the same performance (with `clear` version requiring a bit less operations than other two, although the performance hit is likely to be non-quantifiable), but version (1) of `container.clear` is the most clear (in terms of code readability) of them all, so I'd go with it.

It's worth noting that `list.swap(std::list<some_type>{});` is a compilation error, as `std::list::swap` doesn't have an overload for an rvalue reference, and only accepts non-const lvalue references. Ditto for `std::set::swap`. You'd have to create a named temporary object and swap with it.

Comment: @NeilButterworth, because they will do the same thing. They will call destructors of all objects in the containers and free the memory allocated.

Comment: But doesn't this, `list.swap(std::list<some_type>{});`  construct a new, nameless object?

Comment: Welcome back, @Neil.

Comment: @NeilButterworth, it does. But since construction of an empty list is a trivial operation, I do not see it affecting the performance in any meaningful way.

Comment: It may be trivial, but I would suggest it is more complex than simply calling clear().

Comment: @NeilButterworth, in my analysis of codegen, creating an empty automatic `std::list` object is translated into `subq    $40, %rsp`. I doubt you could quantify it. It's worth noting that the code as written is non compilable - there is no swap for rvalues.

Comment: subq allocates a stack frame - the compiler must also call a constructor on the allocated frame, and in the code you posted it must also call swap(). None of this comes for free.

Comment: @NeilButterworth, constructor of empty list is also a couple of `mov` to zero out the members. I do not think we are getting anywhere with this discussion. Granted, there are a bit more operations with creation of empty list and swap, rather than plain clear, but I do not think you can quantify the perofrmance. The main reason to use `clear` is because it is readable. Nevertheless, I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

All three are equally "reliable".

The version with `.clear()` is obviously the clearest. :)

Seriously, though, use the function that's named for the task, and which was specifically added for the task. There is no need for arcane "tricks" here. Write self-documenting code.

Comment: I got curious because of the black sheep `std::vector` :)